# Right-Click on a PyGTK Hbox in an Expander

Tags: python, events, pygtk, expander, hbox

I've got a gtk.Expander object, containing in its label a gtk.HBox, which packed a gtk.Image and a gtk.Label.
I want to launch a Webbrowser when the HBox is right-clicked.
Here is my code:

```
def launchBrowser(widget, host, event):
    print event
    print host
    if event.type == gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS:
        if event.button == 3:
            webbrowser.open(host, 1)
            print "right click"

def addServer(self, loginfo):
    main_expand = gtk.Expander()
    main_led = gtk.Image()
    if int(loginfo["main"]) == 0:
        main_led.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_STOP, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
    else:
        main_led.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)

    main_srvname = gtk.Label(loginfo["srvname"])

    expand_title = gtk.HBox(False, 2)
    expand_title.pack_start(main_led, False, True, 0)
    expand_title.pack_start(main_srvname, True, True, 0)

    main_srvname.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
    main_srvname.connect_object('event', self.launchBrowser, loginfo["host"])
    main_srvname.emit('event', gtk.gdk.Event(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK))

    main_expand.set_property("label-widget", expand_title)
```

Problem is that when I pass my cursor on this HBox, I correctly received the event. But when I clicked nothing happen. I think it's because the click event is intercept by the Expander.

Anyhelp is welcome =)
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I also tried that:

```
    main_srvname = gtk.Label(loginfo["srvname"])
    eventbox = gtk.EventBox()
    eventbox.add(main_srvname)
    eventbox.connect_object('button-press-event', self.launchBrowser, loginfo["host"])

    # Titre de l'expand box 
    expand_title = gtk.HBox(False, 2)
    expand_title.pack_start(main_led, False, True, 0)
    expand_title.pack_start(eventbox, True, True, 0)
```

Not working either...

EDIT2:
As requested by Jeremy, here a self-contained code, just copy-paste it you lazyboy!

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.addServer()

    def launchBrowser(widget, host, event):
        print event
        if event.type == gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS:
            if event.button == 3:
                print "click"

    def addServer(self):
        main_expand = gtk.Expander()
        main_led = gtk.Image()
        main_led.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_STOP, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)

        main_srvname = gtk.Label("srvname")
        main_srvname.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        main_srvname.connect_object('button-press-event', self.launchBrowser, "host")

        expand_title = gtk.HBox(False, 2)
        expand_title.pack_start(main_led, False, True, 0)
        expand_title.pack_start(main_srvname, True, True, 0)
        main_expand.set_property("label-widget", expand_title)

        self.add(main_expand)
        self.show_all()

def main():
    MainWindow()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you post a self-contained example of your problem, you'll get answers from people who are bored and want to play around with something. If not, then you're limiting yourself to basically people who already know your answer off the top of their head, which may be a small population.

Comment: Post a relatively short, self-contained script so that people can easily run it and see your problem. In general, that will always get you more and faster answers here.

Answer (score -1):

Small change in your code.

Add "button-press-event" on Expander widget instead of Label widget

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
   def __init__(self):
     gtk.Window.__init__(self)
     self.set_default_size(300, 300)
     self.addServer()

   def launchBrowser(self, widget, event, host, *args):
      if event.type == gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS:
        if event.button == 3:
            print "click"
     # Normal behaviour of Expander on single click
      expand = widget.get_expanded()
      if not expand: widget.set_expanded(True)
      else: widget.set_expanded(False)

  def addServer(self):
    main_expand = gtk.Expander()
    main_led = gtk.Image()
    main_led.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_STOP, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)

    main_srvname = gtk.Label("srvname")
    main_expand.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
    main_expand.connect('button-press-event', self.launchBrowser, 'host')

    expand_title = gtk.HBox(False, 2)
    expand_title.pack_start(main_led, False, True, 0)
    expand_title.pack_start(main_srvname, True, True, 0)
    main_expand.set_property("label-widget", expand_title)

    self.add(main_expand)
    self.show_all()

def main():
 MainWindow()
 gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that my expander contain others expander and they are all connected to the launchBrowser function. Thanks anyway but that is not what I want.