# Click on gtk.Expander custom label-widget doesn't work

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm triying to put dinamically several gtk.Expander inside a gtk.VBox and have a custom widget-label with a gtk.HBox with a gtk.Label and a gtk.Button/gtk.Image inside it to have a delete button, something similar to some list widgets found on MacOS X, for example at Automator ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWMsz.png)). Look the close button at the right of the title bar of the expanders: that's *just* exactly what i would like to have.

The problem is that when i click on the delete gtk.Button/gtk.Image, the expander gets closed or opened, instead of the gtk.Button click/gtk.Image event-notify-release callback being called, so the event is being captured by the gtk.Expander.

I have opened a new question since this problem is similar to the one from [Right-Click on a PyGTK Hbox in an Expander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160543/right-click-on-a-pygtk-hbox-in-an-expander) but there they didn't found a solution, and also because a better solution would be to find a specific widget for that task (if exists) instead to hack with the expander... :-D

Comment: Could You do it? I'm also interested in this matter. would be really nice if you could add some code and accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating your own custom widget, perhaps inheriting from `Expander`. [Here](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm) is a tutorial on subclassing widgets in PyGTK.

Comment: At this moment i'm inheriting from gtk.Expander but by other things related to my project, so it's not new for me :-) I'll take a look to your link and come back with results later (it's a personal project, now i'm working), but it seems very complete and promising... :-)